# phpMyAdmin on IIS7.5 permission not granted

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I am trying to get phpMyAdmin working on a server with IIS7.5 installed.  We have done the following and cannot get access to phpMyAdmin working:

1. MySql installed
2. Windows Server 2008 running IIS7.5
3. Followed this tutorial: [enter link description here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-phpMyAdmin-on-Your-Windows-PC)
4. Created a new site and added phpMyAdmin directory beneath it as an application (I can see the subdirectories of the phpMyAdmin root on this application)
5. Navigating to the subdomain set up for the application indicates we do not have sufficient permissions.  I gave users and administrator read/write access for the site and the application:

   HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized

   You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

I feel like we are very close, but I am unsure what other permissions need to be set to gain access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to IIS 7.5, but I believe typically you would need to give the IIS user read permission on the phpMyAdmin folder, files, and subdirectory. You mention giving permission to users and administrators, but I don't think the IIS user would fall in to either of those categories.